# How to make connexion between swifty iOS client and RABBIT MQ

Tags: ios, rabbitmq

i'm developing a small mobile app and i want to receive notifications push from RABBITmMQ, but the problem i don't know how to connect my swift iOS client with RABBITMQ, by the way RABBITMQ is not installed at my local host
i have some credentials configuration to implement it. the problem is the documentation of RABBIT MQ not mentioned how to connect to this remote host not the local.

Answer (score 1):

To connect RabbitMQ to ios you can use this lib:
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-objc-client

About remote connection, follow this example:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-swift.html

here the code:

```
let conn = RMQConnection(uri: "amqp://user:pass@myrabbitserver.com:5672",
                         delegate: RMQConnectionDelegateLogger())
```